# Java-How to reimplement method that evaluates an arithmetic expression so that it does not require user to input parenthesis

Tags: java, stack

I have a method that evaluates an arithmetic expression. This method requires that the expression entered by the user to be fully parenthesized. How can I re implement this method so that the user is not required to parenthesize their expression? and therefore the expression is evaluated using rules of precedence.

```
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.Scanner;
public static float evaluate(String s)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(s);       
      Stack<Float> numbers = new Stack<Float>( );
      Stack<Character> operations = new Stack<Character>( );
      String next;
      char first;

      while (input.hasNext( ))
      {
     if (input.hasNext(FLOAT))
     {
        next = input.findInLine(FLOAT);
        numbers.push(new Float(next));
     }
     else
     {
        next = input.findInLine(CHARACTER);
            first = next.charAt(0);

        switch (first)
        {
        case '+': // Addition
        case '-': // Subtraction
        case '*': // Multiplication
        case '/': // Division
           operations.push(first);
           break;
        case ')': // Right parenthesis
           evaluateStackTops(numbers, operations);
           break;
        case '(': // Left parenthesis
           break;
        default : // Illegal character
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal character");
        }
     }
      }
      if (numbers.size( ) != 1)
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal input expression");
      return numbers.pop( );
   }
```

Comment: Do you want a method for postfix evaluation in java that does not require any parenthesis?

Comment: Yes, im working on converting an infix expression to postfix, then evaluating the expression

Comment: So where is the problem coming? in the conversion from infix to postfix or in the evaluation?

Comment: I'm having more of an issue in the conversion from infix to postfix

Comment: Time to read up about parsers, trees and Backus Naur Form OP.

Comment: For giving a parenthesized *expression* as input, use a character array, if even after that you have any problem then read this question and all the answers related to it, if even after that you have trouble then ask: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/167564-check-validity-algorithm-convert-infixt-postfix-precedence-needed.html (through this method you don't need parsers or trees - but don't look at the solution code given in this - try it yourself first + don't go for shunting yard algorithm at this level)

Comment: As long as my Math knowlage tells me,  paranthesies has its purpose, and if they are used that measns that they are required (ommit the examples of double,tripple,nthiple paranthesis) so why would you like to ommit them in the first place